# Drawing at exact positions in Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, draw-mode

It's perhaps an easy question, but I cannot find the way to do it: In Grease Pencil when drawing a straight line how can I set it's start and end position specifying their (x,y,z) coordinates?
I've the same problem trying to set the center of a circle at a precise (x,y,z) position.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After drawing with the grease pencil you can select parts of the line like you would a vertex/vertices ( the line tool would only have two points ) and can use the number pad/arrow keys and snap tools to move them around as well as using the keys X, Y and Z during movement to restraint. For exact positioning of the cursor i use an empty object and move the cursor to the selected empty ( or part of model ) for specific tweaks.

You can use shift+s for some control over the cursor.

EDIT - You can use left control to use snap temporarily instead of having it on all the time ( the magnet icon ).